# Block user from another user route laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

I am building application where user can upload images. After user clicks on his uploaded image then laravel redirects him to route /images/{image_id} where user can get details of his image and probably delete image if he  wants. Now the problem is when I manually write this route in browser with another image id that belongs to another user image, then I can open his view with his uploaded image details. How can I block user from this route if this image doesnt belongs to him?
Route in web.php:

```
Route::get('/images/{image_id}', 'ImageController@show');
```

This is method in ImageController that redirects user to show image view:

```
    public function show($id){
    $image = Image::findOrFail($id);
    return view('user.show_image', compact('image'));
}
```

Is it good option to try something like that:

```
    public function show($id){
    $image = Image::findOrFail($id);
    if(Auth::user()->id != $image->user_id)
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    return view('user.show_image', compact('image'));
}
```

..or I should use some kind of middleware. Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb; If you're going to end up doing this multiple times in your code, use a function (or in this case a middleware). So for a single route, you can do it in the associated function, but on multiple routes, best to use a middleware.

Comment: I think your approach to put it in the controller is best in this situation. You *could* put it in a middleware, but you would need to make an additional database query to retrieve the image's ``user_id``. So, in this case, I think your solution is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel policies https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies

create a policy for Image call it ImagePolicy.php and add this method :

```
public function view(User $user, Image $image) 
{
   return $user->id === $image->user_id
}
```

in your controller @show :

```
$this->authorize('view', $image);
```

or if you don't like policies :

```
abort_if($user->id !== $image->user_id, 404)
```